# How can I merge these 2 FFmpeg commands?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have two commands which are part of a larger set of commands. Basically I need to merge these two into one command to speed things up.

```
ffmpeg -y -f concat -safe 0 -protocol_whitelist "file,http,https,tcp,tls" -i "photos.txt" -i "mainscreen.png" -i "audio.mp3" -filter_complex "scale=3840x2160,zoompan=z='if(lte(zoom,1.0),1.2,max(1.001,zoom-0.0015))':x='iw/2-(iw/zoom/2)':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)':s=1280x720:fps=15:d=120, overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2, drawtext=fontfile=font.otf:text='%%~ni':fontcolor=black:fontsize=32:x=90:y=582" -preset veryfast -tune stillimage -shortest -pix_fmt yuv420p "slideshow.mp4"

ffmpeg -y -i "slideshow.mp4" -filter_complex "[0:a]showwaves=mode=cline:s=110x36:r=15:scale=sqrt:colors=0x222222,colorkey=0x000000:0.01:0.1,format=yuva420p[v];[0:v][v]overlay=77:444,scale=1280:720[outv]" -map "[outv]" -map 0:a -preset veryfast "done.mp4"
```

Firstly creates a slideshow and adds text, then draws a showwaves effect onto the video.

### Update

From Gyan's response, and after tinkering for a while, it kind of works how I needed it to. It does what I wanted, but keeps throwing "depreciated pixel format" error. Here's the updated command once I finished. What is the problem, and is the command written properly?

```
ffmpeg -y -f concat -safe 0 -protocol_whitelist "file,http,https,tcp,tls" -i "images.txt" -i "screen.png" -i "audio.mp3" -filter_complex "scale=3840x2160,zoompan=z='if(lte(zoom,1.0),1.2,max(1.001,zoom-0.0015))':x='iw/2-(iw/zoom/2)':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)':s=1280x720:fps=15:d=120, overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2, drawtext=fontfile=Assets/Fonts/font.otf:text='%%~ni':fontcolor=black:fontsize=32:x=90:y=582[v];[2:a]showwaves=mode=cline:s=110x36:r=15:scale=sqrt:colors=0x222222,colorkey=0x000000:0.01:0.1,format=yuva420p[w];[v][w]overlay=77:444,scale=1280:720[outv]" -map "[outv]" -map 2:a -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -preset veryfast -shortest -pix_fmt yuv420p "done.mp4"
```

### Second update

Thanks to Gyan for helping me better understand the command. Here is the final code which does what I need:

```
ffmpeg -y -f concat -safe 0 -protocol_whitelist "file,http,https,tcp,tls" -i "images.txt" -i "screen.png" -i "tmp.audio.mp3" -filter_complex "[0]scale=3840x2160,zoompan=z='if(lte(zoom,1.0),1.2,max(1.001,zoom-0.0015))':x='iw/2-(iw/zoom/2)':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)':s=1280x720:fps=15:d=120, overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2, drawtext=fontfile=font.otf:text='%%~ni':fontcolor=black:fontsize=32:x=90:y=582[v];[2:a]showwaves=mode=cline:s=110x36:r=15:scale=sqrt:colors=0x222222,colorkey=0x000000:0.01:0.1,format=yuva420p[w];[v][w]overlay=77:444,scale=1280:720[outv]" -map "[outv]" -map 2:a -preset veryfast -shortest -pix_fmt yuv420p "done.mp4"
```

Only change from Gyan's code is I removed [p];[1][p] and replaced with a comma to achieve what I needed. Seems to work perfect now, ignoring the depreciated pixels warning.

Comment: (Please don't add answers, or commentary on answers, to solved questions - you can use comments for that if you like. Questions should be preserved in a format that allows for new answers to be provided).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

`ffmpeg -y -f concat -safe 0 -protocol_whitelist "file,http,https,tcp,tls" -i "photos.txt" -i "mainscreen.png" -i "audio.mp3" -filter_complex "[0]scale=3840x2160,zoompan=z='if(lte(zoom,1.0),1.2,max(1.001,zoom-0.0015))':x='iw/2-(iw/zoom/2)':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)':s=1280x720:fps=15:d=120[p];[p][1]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2, drawtext=fontfile=font.otf:text='%%~ni':fontcolor=black:fontsize=32:x=90:y=582[v];[2:a]showwaves=mode=cline:s=110x36:r=15:scale=sqrt:colors=0x222222,colorkey=0x000000:0.01:0.1,format=yuva420p[w];[v][w]overlay=77:444,scale=1280:720[outv]" -map "[outv]" -map 2:a -preset veryfast -shortest -pix_fmt yuv420p "slideshow.mp4"`

Comment: hello sir thank you for your response. i tried your command but i receive this error:
Stream map '0:a' matches no streams.

i tried playing around with it but i couldnt get it to work, being inexperienced

Comment: i updated the question, you got me closer to where I wanted to be so thank you

Comment: You can ignore the "depreciated pixel format" messages - it is shown when JPEGs or certain TIFFs are read. Your latest command is missing the labels I added - don't do that. If you remove labels, you're relying on ffmpeg to automatically route inputs within the filtergraph. I had already corrected the 2:a map. I don't see any other positive change in your latest command.

Comment: as i see, thank you for explaining. in that case the only thing needed to do was remove [p];[1][p] and replace with a comma as it wouldnt display the image overlay otherwise. I have updated the question again. would you kindly take one more look incase i made more mistakes? thanks again

Comment: Do you want to overlay the screen on top of the photos or the other way around?

Comment: screen.png is semi-transparant and goes over the top of the slideshow. sorry, I should have mentioned that. my bad.

Comment: perfect. thank you, you've helped a lot and i am very grateful